# Cannot use transaction manager - autowiring ends with exception

Tags: java, spring

I would never ever thought I could had so huge problems with spring configuration, but I cannot get my project work with @Transactional annotations at all (I'm using JPA). Each time I am getting **No qualifying bean of type** in entities where @Transactional annotation is used. My application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">



    <!-- we can use annotations -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!--&lt;!&ndash; package to look for annotated classes &ndash;&gt;-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="a.b.c.d.service" />


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- we will manage transactions with annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <!--&lt;!&ndash; data source for our database &ndash;&gt;-->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle11:1521/deviso" />
        <property name="username" value="aaa" />
        <property name="password" value="xxx" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="a.b.c.d.domain" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="a.b.c.d.repository"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory">
    <!--transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager">-->

    </jpa:repositories>

</beans>
```

Can you please give my some advice what's wrong with my settings?

EDIT: My stacktrace:

```
2015-07-13 19:31:38,230 ERROR [org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.InvocationHandlerJAXWS] (default task-3) JBAS015594: Method invocation failed with exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Injection of autowired dependencies failed for class [class a.b.c.d.ws.XMLProviderEndpointImpl$$$view1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private a.b.c.d.service.XMLProfileService a.b.c.d.ws.XMLProviderEndpointImpl.profileService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [a.b.c.d.service.XMLProfileService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Injection of autowired dependencies failed for class [class a.b.c.d.ws.XMLProviderEndpointImpl$$$view1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private a.b.c.d.service.XMLProfileService a.b.c.d.ws.XMLProviderEndpointImpl.profileService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [a.b.c.d.service.XMLProfileService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandler.getComponentView(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:117)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.performInvocation(JBossWSInvoker.java:175)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:237)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:69)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:146)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:241)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:97)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:131)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Injection of autowired dependencies failed for class [class a.b.c.d.ws.XMLProviderEndpointImpl$$$view1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private a.b.c.d.service.XMLProfileService a.b.c.d.ws.XMLProviderEndpointImpl.profileService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [a.b.c.d.service.XMLProfileService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processInjection(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:319) [spring-beans-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.java:85) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.<init>(SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.java:68) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at a.b.c.d.ws.XMLProviderEndpointImpl.<init>(XMLProviderEndpointImpl.java:25) [classes:]
    at a.b.c.d.ws.XMLProviderEndpointImpl$$$view1.<init>(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at org.jboss.invocation.proxy.AbstractClassFactory.newInstance(AbstractClassFactory.java:225)
    at org.jboss.invocation.proxy.ProxyFactory.newInstance(ProxyFactory.java:270)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$DefaultViewInstanceFactory.createViewInstance(ViewService.java:271)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.createInstance(ViewService.java:177)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.createInstance(ViewService.java:173)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandler.getComponentView(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:83)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private a.b.c.d.service.XMLProfileService a.b.c.d.ws.XMLProviderEndpointImpl.profileService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [a.b.c.d.service.XMLProfileService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522) [spring-beans-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) [spring-beans-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processInjection(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:316) [spring-beans-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [a.b.c.d.service.XMLProfileService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1118) [spring-beans-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967) [spring-beans-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862) [spring-beans-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:494) [spring-beans-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 66 more
```

The code is simple. DTOs has no logic, just primitive types.

```
@Transactional
public void update(String password, XMLProviderProfileDTO dto) {
}
```

When I delete the Transactional annotation, everything works, so I assume something with proxifying the transtactional classes.

Comment: Post the stack trace and the code using `@Transactional`. Your statement doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Stacktrace added. This guy had something similar obviously, but I cannot fix it with his settings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815756/injection-of-autowired-dependencies-failed-while-using-transactional

Comment: You have to declare a spring bean of type `a.b.c.d.service.XMLProfileService`

Comment: Please post the entire XMLProfileService class not only the method youre using.

Comment: Ok I got it. My XMLProfileService implemented interface Authorizable (my interface) so this service needed to implement checkIfAllowed(password). This did not smell good for transaction manager. Later I will post the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Spring by default uses proxies for AOP and by default it uses interface based proxies. Also imho when using interfaces you should program to interfaces and not concrete classes... To fix add `proxy-target-class="true"` to your `<tx:annotation-driven />`. Or create an interface containing the needed methods (`ProfileService` or something like that).